# Error when Authenticate Orgs

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, salesforcedx-cli-auth

I'm having a very frustrated problem where Visual Studio Code show error everytime I want to authenticate an org. I use CMD and it working fine but when I try to work on Visual Studio Code it show the error:

NOTE: Im working under Corp FireWall with VPN

```
{ Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs:
   [ '/c',
     'start',
     '""',
     '/b',
     'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code^&client_id=PlatformCLI^&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1717%2FOauthRedirect^&state=9e09d65d19c2^&prompt=login^&scope=refresh_token%20api%20web^&code_challenge=yjKn-leNdaPfMaR1sxoitufitpHaNAwrcfvZgcHFnxM' ] }
{ Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs:
   [ '/c',
     'start',
     '""',
     '/b',
     'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code^&client_id=PlatformCLI^&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1717%2FOauthRedirect^&state=9e09d65d19c2^&prompt=login^&scope=refresh_token%20api%20web^&code_challenge=yjKn-leNdaPfMaR1sxoitufitpHaNAwrcfvZgcHFnxM' ] }
{ Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs:
   [ '/c',
     'start',
     '""',
     '/b',
     'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code^&client_id=PlatformCLI^&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1717%2FOauthRedirect^&state=9e09d65d19c2^&prompt=login^&scope=refresh_token%20api%20web^&code_challenge=yjKn-leNdaPfMaR1sxoitufitpHaNAwrcfvZgcHFnxM' ] }
```

I checked Task manager and I can see the Node.js freezed. 
Please help me !
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

1. Run command prompt   ( >  > - >  )
2. Run the command:  -
3. CTRL+F, to search for
4. Note the number displayed in the   in the same row where 1717 was found. In my case, it's
5. Open Task Manager > Click on Details Tab > Sort by PID
6. Locate the number from step 4 (in my case )
7. Right-Click > End Task
8. Go back to VS Code and run the command again " :   "

---

Also check this :

1. Uninstall if any external/extra Node.js is installed in your PC.
2. Reinstall VS-Code & Salesforce CLI
3. Try restarting your PC as a particular port maybe busy.
4. Try connecting to a different network.

Checkout this link too - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli_firewall.htm

Upvote this & select as best answer if this helps you..!!